# Ruby rest-client gem always causing OpenTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, rest-client

I'm trying to use the [API of the Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_signature_v2.htm#single), and trying to use the API using `curl` works perfectly and returns the results almost immediately:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/CFU0000008000"
```

However, when I try to run this in irb using rest-client, it always causes a `RestClient::Exceptions::OpenTimeout (Timed out connecting to server)` exception:

```
RestClient.get "https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/CFU0000008000"
```

If I increase the open timeout, to say 240, it works and gets the results eventually but it takes forever. I tried uninstalling and installing rails again, but I haven't been able to figure out the issue.

I'm running rails 6.0.2.2, ruby 2.7, and rest-client 2.1.0 on macOS Catalina.

Update: on researching this further, I see that the `RestClient::Exceptions::OpenTimeout` exception wraps `Net::OpenTimeout` so this is something not specific to rest-client maybe.

Comment: Is ruby running in the same environment as curl? Same proxy settings, interface etc?